# Is there any problem to use for loop to create objects?

Tags: python, oop, for-loop

I'm iterating through an excel sheet and trying to create objects for each value contained in cell.

I'm first creating a SET with all the values encounterd and then i'm 'for looping' throug this set to create each object (i know thiis not well optimized)

The problem is:

After i iterate through the set to create the objects i try to print an atribute and i receive the message(example: NameError: name 'BIDI' is not defined).

However, if I print inside the for loop 'asset.name', the object will exist.  So what i am doing wrong ?  Why can't i see the object created after the loop.

```
class Ativo:

def __init__(self,nome = "",qtd_total=0,pm=0):

    self.nome = nome
    self.qtd_total = qtd_total
    self.pm = pm





for asset in set_ativo:   #set_ativo is the SET with all objects to be created

    asset = Ativo(nome=asset)     #Assuming that the first on the list is called BIDI
    print(asset.nome)       #this works
    print(asset.qtd_total)  #this works
    print(BIDI.nome)      #THIS DOES NOT WORK  -- > NameError: name 'BIDI' is not defined


print(BIDI.nome)     #THIS DOES NOT WORK ---> NameError: name 'BIDI' is not defined
```

Comment: Just like the compiler, we do not know what `BIDI` and `BIDI4` are.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. For starters, I think you have a typo `BIDI4` should be `BIDI` based, on your comments. But more importantly, why do you think it should work? Is `BIDI` defined anywhere? What is `BIDI`? My feeling is that the Excel library that you are using is managing the lifecycle of the objects in a non-standard way, but it's difficult to tell without more context. If indeed `BIDI` is not defined anywhere the kind of error is getting is expected.

Comment: Also, if you are thinking that the `BIDI` variable should be defined because the first asset in the set is the string `"BIDI"` then no, that's not how it works. For `BIDI` to be defined you gotta have `BIDI = something of your choice` before you use it in a `print` or anywhere else.

Comment: Sorry. I typed it wrong when I was copying here.

"BIDI" is the first string registered in the SET called set_ATIVO. (see below)

{'BIDI', 'XPML11', 'SUZB3', 'B3SA3', 'MGLU3', 'BCFF11', 'KNRI11', 'BBPO11', 'IVVB11', 'HGLG11', 'BRKM5', 'ITSA4', 'PETR4', 'GGRC11', 'RLOG3'}

So when the for loop startss, it reads BIDI and creates an Object called BIDI in the Class Ativo.

After that, to verify, i call asset.nome (for the firts loop will be BIDI.nome) to see if it correctly implemented the object. And it worls. But if i call, after that, 'BIDI.nome", it does not works

Comment: So, as your last answer, i cannot create objects using a 'for loop' through a set ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having a problem with "scoping of variables".

Before:

```
targetName = "Mark"
for name,phone in people.items():
    if name == targetName:
        foundPhoneNumber = phone
```

But foundPhoneNumber will be out of scope.

After:

```
targetName = "Mark"
foundPhoneNumber = None
for name,phone in people.items():
    if name == targetName:
        foundPhoneNumber = phone
if not foundPhoneNumer is None:
    print("Found phone number:", foundPhoneNumber)
else:
    print("Phone number (person) not found"
```

So now "foundPhoneNumber" is still in scope once the loop ends, and you can check if it is None or not.
Mark

Comment: So when my code ends the loop, the information is vanished ?

If this was the case, print BIDI.nome inside the 'loop' would work, dont? You can see that i printed **('asset.name')** when asset was _BIDI_(first loop) but just after i tried 'BIDI.name' and does not work. There is something wrong when defining the obejct, as @damix911 said.

Comment: "vanished" meaning "no longer in-scope", then yes.  Variables defined inside of a loop go out of scope, aka "vanish", when that loop ends.  So I routinely put the variable outside of the loop, just above the "for ..." line.

Comment: I understand, so how should I do this case?
The objects I want to create are in a column of cells in Excel.
Before the loop I have no information to declare.


in short, I want to create several objects with their respective attributes taken from an excel spreadsheet without having to declare them one by one.